# Cannot get JSON data in response from Mock requests in python

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Following is my unittest code to Mock an HTTP request to a locally stored Google Cloud Function which returns json response

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock
from cloud_functions import main
from Flask import jsonify

data = { ... }
headers = { ... }

req = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data, headers=headers)
resp = main.my_function(req)
```

The following are the kinds of errors I am facing on trying to get the json data in the response.

### Attempt 1

```py
json_data = resp.json()
value = json_data['some_key']
```

**Error**

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

### Attempt 2

```py
value = resp['some_key']
```

**Error**

> TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

### Attempt 3

```py
json_data = jsonify(resp)
value = json_data['some_key']
```

**Error**

> TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using this code.

```py
json_data = resp.json
value = json_data['some_key']
```

Everything works as expected now.